# b2c and b2e integration with Azure AD

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

What is ideal way of integrating both  Azure AD b2c and b2e in an angular application, can we give two separate buttons on  login page and can redirect based on user selection? Is that feasible? or via social login but that would force b2e tenants to signup with b2c?
Any reference link or good suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Lets answer your question one by one.

1. can we give two separate buttons on login page and can redirect based on user selection?
   Yes, you have to use azure ad b2c and there you can add flows for azure ad b2b (b2e).
   2.Is that feasible?
   Yes, I have used it personally with react js and it works flawlessly.
2. or via social login but that would force b2e tenants to signup with b2c?
   it depends on the usecase.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider  <- these are the providers
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow <- this one you should use

Comment: for 1 are you using redirects or popups, and are you using it in one single application or are they micro apps? I am facing issue after redirects in angular.

Comment: when you say you have to use azure b2c and there you can add flow for azure b2b means b2b/b2e user  will be registered under b2c tenant?

Comment: we have used redirect flow, whenever user hit our application they will be redirected to identity page (which is ad b2c), and after successful authentication they will redirect back to application.  just try to follow this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-angular-spa-app#:~:text=To%20enable%20your%20app%20to%20sign%20in%20with,During%20app%20registration%2C%20you%20specify%20the%20redirect%20URI.  (might help)

Comment: yaa so you have to use b2c, and there you will have a button to use azure b2e (which is azure AD), when user will click on that, they will  be redirected to ad page for further processing.